# Where is the first good moment to take a screenshot in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I would like to make a screenshot of my view when view is loaded. I use this method:

```
- (UIImage *)screenshot {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.opaque, 0.0f);

    if( [self respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)] ) {
        [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    } else {
        [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    }

    UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return screenshot;
}
```

The `screenshot` method was tested and works well. I am using the method in my UIViewController in `viewDidLoad`. The problem is that the result is a grey image! It's mean that view is not loaded in `viewDidLoad` method. The same issue can be observe in `viewDidAppear`. So `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` are too early. I have made workaround in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
__weak MyUIViewController *weakSelf = self;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^() {
    UIImage* image = [weakSelf.view screenshot]
    // do sth with image...
});
```

How to make a screenshot without `dispatach_async` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take snapshot / screenshot of whole UIView - iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350979/take-snapshot-screenshot-of-whole-uiview-iphone)

Comment: `screenshot` method works well but there is no view when `viewDidLoad`

Comment: have you tried in ViewWillAppear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
- (UIImage *)screenshot {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

[UIView-JTViewToImage project also usefull.](https://github.com/ioscodesnippet/UIView-JTViewToImage)

Comment: Yes! Do not use: `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates`

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates` method of `UIView`:

```
[self.view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

Comment: `screenshot` works ok. The question is when to use this method. I don't want to make a snapshot of whole screen.

Comment: I would try it in `viewDidAppear:`. You can screenshot any view you want, just replace `self.view` with the view you want to capture.

Comment: Hmmm `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates` returns good `UIVIew` in `viewDidLoad` method. But i need `UIImage` so I convert `UIView` to `UIImage` but the result is grey image. So it looks like there is a problem with conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

New API has been added since iOS 7, that should provide efficient way of getting snapshot

`snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` renders the view into a `UIView` with `unmodifiable` content

`resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:afterScreenUpdates:withCapInsets` : same thing, but with `resizable insets`

```
drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:
```

same thing if you need all subviews to be drawn too (like labels, buttons...)

Hope it helps.